# $.getJSON returning "undefined" values, data reads [object Object]

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, dom-events, getjson

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm new to JSON and I've been trying to use `$.getJSON` to fill some form fields with no luck.

I started chopping pieces out until I was left simply testing my response from the server (my server is providing JSON when the URL listed below is viewed in a browser):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').live('click', function(){
        $.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/core/api/master-assembly/16', function(data) { 
        // alert(data); // uncomment for debug
           $('#showdata').html("<p>item1="+data.afAgeCounter+" item2="+data.afWordCounter+" item3="+data.idNumber+"</p>");
        });
    });
});
```

My JSON data looks something like:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"afWordCounter":123,"afAgeCounter":456,"idNumber":789, ...
```

When I run this script, I get the output:

> item1=undefined item2=undefined item3=undefined

If I uncomment the

```
alert(data);
```

all I get in return is `[object Object]`

So what gives here?

Comment: You can't alert an object, you can however use console.log(data) and view the object in a javascript debugger such as Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're returning doesn't have a `afAgeCounter`, etc. property.  It has a `data` property that has those.

You need to get that `data` property first.

```
if(data.success){
    data = data.data;
    $('#showdata').html("<p>item1="+data.afAgeCounter+" item2="+data.afWordCounter+" item3="+data.idNumber+"</p>");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm, I appreciate the explanation too.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$('#showdata').html("<p>item1="+data.data.afAgeCounter+" item2="+data.data.afWordCounter+" item3="+data.data.idNumber+"</p>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be accessing it like this:

```
data.data.afWordCounter
```

since your json variable has this structure:

```
data = {
    "success":true,
    "data":{
         "afWordCounter":123,"afAgeCounter":456,"idNumber":789,
         ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I wish I could give you all credit for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have eluded to, your entire JSON result is the parameter to your callback - 'data', which is an object.

It has two properties, 'success' and 'data'. 'data' itself is and object {} with it's own properties, afWordCounter, afAgeCounter etc. So to get to the properties of the internal 'data' object you need to use data.data.afWordCounter etc

It may be clearer what's going on if you switch your method body to something like this:

```
    $.getJSON('http://localhost:8000/core/api/master-assembly/16', function(jsonresult)         { 

       $('#showdata').html("<p>item1="+jsonresult.data.afAgeCounter+" item2="+jsonresult.data.afWordCounter+" item3="+jsonresult.data.idNumber+"</p>");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

just piling on here, but if you're ever wondering what's contained in a js object, you can always print it to string using JSON.stringify: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

so, the object in question, you can see what's contained in it via:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(mysteryObject));
```

or

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(mysteryObject);
```